# Please help, getting a contradiction with non-commutative tensor products

Tags: matrices, quaternions, semi-simple-rings

Let $D/{\mathbb Q}$ be a quaternion algebra and $K / {\mathbb Q}$ a quadratic field extension that is contained in $D$.

Then I would like to see $D$ as a module over $K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} D$ via the morphism
$$
\psi \colon K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} D \rightarrow End_{\mathbb Q}(D), \quad (k \otimes d) \mapsto (x \mapsto d \cdot x \cdot k).
$$
This should give $D$ the structure of an $K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} D$-module. Since $K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} D$ is a simple semi-simple $K$-algebra, we then have $D \cong (K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} D)^r$ for some $r$.

However, comparing dimensions gives me $r = \frac 12$, contradiction.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Maybe you should think more carefully about the module structure you're giving.  It looks to me like you are giving $D$ as both a left $D$ module and a right $K$ module.

Comment: @Kimball Yes, $D$ is a $(D,K)$-bimodule, making it a $D\otimes_\mathbb{Q}K$-module. Why should OP think more carefully about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dim_\mathbb{Q}D=4$ and $\dim_\mathbb{Q}K=2$ we can say $D$ is $2$D as a right $K$-vector space.

The module structure is a $K$-algebra homomorphism $D\otimes_\mathbb{Q}K\to \mathrm{End}_K(D)$. Both sides of this have the same dimension as $K$-vector spaces, so to confirm this is an algebra isomorphism it suffices to show it is one-to-one, or equivalently its kernel is trivial.

Since $K$ is 2D over $\mathbb{Q}$, all elements of $A=D\otimes_\mathbb{Q} K$ are expressible as $d\otimes k$ or as a simple combination $d_1\otimes k_1+d_2\otimes k_2$. In the first case, we can apply such an algebra element to the module element $1\in D$ to get $dk=0$, which implies $d\otimes k=0$, so next assume there is a kernel element which is not a pure tensor; we can multiply such an element by a pure tensor to get a kernel element of the form $1\otimes1-d\otimes k$. If we apply this to the module element $1\in D$ we get $1-dk=0$, or IOW $d=k^{-1}$. The element $1\otimes1-k^{-1}\otimes k$ is $0$ if $k\in\mathbb{Q}$, so assume otherwise. Since $D$ is central simple over $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists an $\ell\in D$ for which $k\ell\ne\ell k$, and then if we apply $1\otimes1-k^{-1}\otimes k$ to $\ell$ we get $\ell-k^{-1}\ell k=0$, a contradiction, so the kernel is trivial.

Therefore we conclude $A\cong M_2(K)$ is not a simple module over itself and it makes sense $D\cong K^2$ can be a $K$-module over it. Indeed, $M_2(K)$ has two left ideals, corresponding to matrices with first or second column zeroed out, so there ought to be two corresponding ideals of $A$.

Suppose $K$ is generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by a square root of $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ we call $u$. Then $\frac{1}{2a}(1\otimes a\pm u\otimes u)$ are two orthogonal idempotents $e_\pm$ yielding $A=Ae_+\oplus Ae_-$, just as planned.

We can refine this to the corresponding Peirce decompositions

$$ A\cong (e_+Ae_+) \oplus (e_+Ae_-) \oplus (e_-Ae_+) \oplus (e_-Ae_-) $$

$$ M_2(K) \,\cong\, 
[\begin{smallmatrix} K & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}] \,\oplus\,
[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & K \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}] \,\oplus\,
[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ K & 0 \end{smallmatrix}] \,\oplus\,
[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & K \end{smallmatrix}] $$

and the isomorphism $A\cong M_2(K)$ respects the graded $K$-algebra structures above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am still a bit confused by your statement that $M_2(K)$ is not a simple algebra. In many places, the matrix algebra is taken as a prime example of an algebra that is simple (although there it means that the algebra has only two, two sided ideals, which seems something else than what you refer to). Are there several in-equivalent definitions of "simple algebra/simple ring" going around? (because that could have been the origin of my confusion).

Comment: @mnr I misspoke, it is simple as an algebra in the sense that it has no two-sided ideals, it's just not simple as a module over itself. Being simple as an algebra does not imply all modules are free over it, though, which is the wrong assumption in your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that clears everything up